# Remove Leading Zeros Except last Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, leading-zero, patindex

Database -  SQL Server 2012

I am currently using the following code:

```
substring(
    SUBSTRING(col001, 59, 8), 
    patindex(
        '%[^0]%', 
        SUBSTRING(col001, 59, 8)
    ),
    10
) as TOTAL_DETAIL_RECORD_COUNT
```

A lot of substrings, I know but it is working for the most part.  There is one catch though.  Some of the column values are `000000000`.  When this is the case, the substring/patindex clause just leaves it as is.  Is there something I can do to turn a value of `000000000` to return `0`. Just one zero?  The length of leading zeros may not always be the same.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: The expected result should just be 0 (one zero) if the value is 000000000.  I think I am just going to do this part in SSRS if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Without more example data it's hard to be sure if this is helpful, but could you not just cast the value to `int` or `bigint`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast your substring as in INT and then convert it back to a string

```
Select cast(cast('000000000' as int) as varchar(25))  -- Returns a string of 0
Select cast(cast('000000025' as int) as varchar(25))  -- Returns a string of 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what database you're using. In Oracle, this would be:

```
select nvl(ltrim(substr(col001, 59, 8), '0'), '0')
from dual;
```

Comment: Sorry I am using SQL Server 2012